# Fixed width div on right, fill remaining width div on left

Tags: html, css

Im searching for a way to have 2 divs as columns where div on right has a fixed width and div on left fill remaining space.

Does anyone happen to know if this can be done?

**My attempt *(renders block2 underneath block1)*:**

```
<style>
.block1 {
   width: auto;
   height: 200px;

   background-color: green;
}
.block2 {
   float: right;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;

   background-color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="block1">test1</div>
<div class="block2">test2</div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="left">left</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.left{
    background:red;

}
.right{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    background:green
}
```

Check this live example http://jsfiddle.net/QHTeS/2/

Comment: I never realised the order in the markup made a difference, thanks!

Comment: happy to help :) ; if it's helpful to you then vote & accept thanks

Comment: its not working in my case.. in my case left is fixed and right has to be filled..

Comment: @mickeymoon that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/QHTeS/485/

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it requires the user to change structure of the code. This shouldn't be acceptable. It violates the entire idea of separating structure from presentation and business logic.

Comment: What if the contents of div on the left needed to be hidden on if they overflow?

Comment: I needed to add `overflow:hidden` to `left` in order to get it to work for me.

Comment: Marked as duplicate question but your answer is the only one managed to provide me with a working solution.

Answer (score 6):

Float *Both* of the elements left:

```
<style>
.block1 {
   width: auto;
   height: 200px;
   float: left;
   background-color: green;
}
.block2 {
   float: left;
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;

   background-color: red;
}
</style>

<div class="block1">test1</div>
<div class="block2">test2</div>
```

You should wrap them in a container as well to prevent messing up the rest of your layout. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/tcFjN/

---

That was *wrong!*

Use `display: table;` on parent and `display: table-cell;` on children:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block1">test1</div>
    <div class="block2">test2</div>
</div>


#wrapper
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.block1 {
       width: auto;
       height: 200px;
       display: table-cell;
       background-color: green;
}
.block2 {
       display: table-cell;
       height: 200px;
       width: 200px;
       background-color: red;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tcFjN/1/

Comment: Kyle, are you sure this code works in chrome? :) For me the green doesn't fill remaining width

Comment: Sorry, I made a slight error, check the EDIT portion of my answer, this definitely makes the green fill the remaining width.

Comment: Aah thanks, the 2nd one definitely works. I like it :)

Comment: An upvote and acceptance is always welcome, unless ou preferred the other method from SAndeep then keep his as marked accepted.

Comment: I like both your answers equally but i read the other 1 first, sorry I wont let me upvote it yet but I will soon as I have enough rep points

Comment: +1 I like this one, very responsive :)

Answer (score 1):

[Check this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5hAN/52/)

Start out with a container `<div>` (`#container`) that holds both the left and right `<div>`s. Float one `<div>` to the right and give it a specific width (320px in my example). Then give the other `<div>` an absolute position starting at the absolute left (0px) and ending at the left edge of the `<div>` on the right (320px).

If you adjust the width of `#container`, the right `<div>` will remain fixed at 320px while the left `<div>` will expand to fill whatever the remaining area is.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution without floats. The only caveat is that I need to use a wrapper. So, if the desired HTML is

```
parent (has a border, margin, padding,...)
  left (fixed width)
  right (variable width, fill the entire space)
```

I must rewrite it as

```
   parent (has a border, margin, padding,...)
      wrapper (has no styling)
        left (fixed width)
        right (variable eidthm, fill the entire space)
```

My HTML is

```
  <div style="border:1px solid black; background:red; margin:10px; padding:10px;" >
    <div style=""> 
      <div style="display:table-cell; padding:10px; min-width:100px; max-width:100px;background:green;">Left</div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; padding:10px; width:100%; background:yellow;">Main content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The main points here are:

- **No use display:table** because then we can not set the border
- The use of min-width, max-width
- The use of width:100%

Comment: If you leave the <div style=""> away it will work as well, so the empty div is obsolete: http://jsfiddle.net/zp77csw6/