# Given two divs on the same line, how can I make the left div fill the remaining horizontal space after I've specified a width for the right div?

Tags: css, width

Here's my an abstraction of my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BsHpj/8/

Here's one I found in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094787/fixed-width-div-on-right-fill-remaining-width-div-on-left) that works: http://jsfiddle.net/QHTeS/2/

Why does his work I want and mine doesn't? All help appreciated.

Here's the less abstracted version of mine: http://jsfiddle.net/nLn3A/

Comment: this is what you need?
http://jsfiddle.net/BsHpj/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is one fixed column on the right and one fluid on the left.

Method 1: Swap order of left and right: http://jsfiddle.net/BsHpj/19/ This method involves the least CSS but it means you have to make your HTML a bit less intuitive. (by Lyn Headley)

Method 2: Use margin-left and margin-right: http://jsfiddle.net/VmaZr/14/ This method has nice HTML but involves more CSS code.  (by DynamicDrive)

Method 3: Format divs as a table: http://jsfiddle.net/BsHpj/9/ Easily understood but a little more CSS (by Oswaldo Acauan).

Answer (score 4):

Your version does not work because you're floating the right div, but not the left one. So the left div is taking up 100% of the width of the parent container and bumping the right div down. If you added `float: left;` to the left div and `float: right;` to the right div you should see them on the same line, with a gap between them.

Think of a float as "shrink-wrapping" the container to the size of the content. By default, a container will usually take up 100% of the width of the parent.

Comment: I think I did as you said but I still can't get the left div to fill the remaining space. http://jsfiddle.net/BsHpj/15/ What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

Swap the order of left and right. Otherwise the first div will fill all the horizontal space.