# Left div liquid width, right div width in px

Tags: html, css

I want to make a HTML layout where the left div adjusts to the window size and the right div has a fixed size. How do I have to set the width of the left one? I cannot do 70% and 30% because the right div has got a fixed size.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j73th/)

HTML

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
```

CSS

```
.left{
height: 100%;
width: 300px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
}

.right{
height: 100%;
width: ....;
background-color: black;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094787/fixed-width-div-on-right-fill-remaining-width-div-on-left?rq=1

Comment: Here is yours http://jsfiddle.net/mhkwQ/

Comment: Does `.left` need to be `float: left` or can it be block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) function, although it isn't [supported](http://caniuse.com/calc) below IE 9 and you need to include the `-moz` and `-webkit` prefixes for FF 15 & Chrome 25 and below. There is also almost no support for it in mobile browsers as @cimmanon pointed out in the comment below.

```
#left{
height: 100%;
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
width: calc(100% - 100px);
background-color: red;
float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j73th/1/

You can also give the `#right` div a negative right margin equal to the width of the `#left` div:

http://jsfiddle.net/j73th/3/

Comment: Wow, you are COOL @ Adrift!

Comment: your code is hiding the text and calc is not supported by all browsers

Comment: `Calc()` is also not supported by a vast majority of mobile browsers.  It's one thing when support for properties like border-radius is missing because it just impacts aesthetics.  Lack of support for `calc()` significantly impacts the ability to use the website.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j73th/2/)

*Note- I am changing the html placing of `right` and `left` div purposely*

html code-

```
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
```

css code-

```
body, html{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#left{
height: 100%;
margin-right:102px;
background-color: red;
} 

#right{
height: 100%;
width: 100px;
float:right;
background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't have to change the structure of code to achieve presentation.

Comment: He shouldn't need to change the order of those elements simply to change the way they are presented on the web page. CSS or unobtrusive Javascript should handle that exclusively. HTML is structure, not presentation. It's a document.

Comment: i understand but I am afraid it is needed to do so and if the html is under development it can be done

Comment: @crush **Do not threaten to 'report' people**. Flag or don't flag. But don't make threats.

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning on the `#left` element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j73th/10/

```
#left
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: -100px;
}

#right
{
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
}
```