# Vertical navbar on desktop and horizontal on mobile with bootstrap3 3

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, markup

I am trying to design basically a navbar that is vertical on desktop and horizontal on mobile.

Desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

My basic idea is to use a media query to make the elements inline-block for mobile:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .fluid-inline{
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

My doubt is with the markup.

I know it should be something along the following lines:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row fluid-inline">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-12">one</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-12">two</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-12">three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="map-container row fluid-inline">
        <div id="map" class="">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is somehow working but broken, the part that is breaking is the map container, might have something to do with the rows being inline?

Tried something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="map" class="">

    </div>
</div>
```

But also not sure.

So my question is basically how the boostrap markup should be, what should be a row, and the cols I have to use.

[Here is a live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/Qar44/4/)

Please note that this markup is not definitive and what I'm looking for is correct markup, so don't hesitate to restructure completely.

Also, I don't really need the actual code, the idea of the correct structure should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this structure?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
            <ul class="my-menu">
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
            <div class="map-container">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

1. I don't think it is a good idea to put the navigation items inside a bootstrap's `col-x-n` classes. You should use a simple `li` for them, and style them.
2. You do not necessarily need another `row` for your *map*, this is actually where your problem is. Instead, you should define another `col` and manipulate it with `col-x-n` classes based on the screen size.

When there are two `col-x-12` classes in a single `row`, the page renders them as stacked each other (what you need on mobile, nav on top, map on bottom).

Here is the **[demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Qar44/5/)**.

Comment: This is a great answer but I came to realize that my question was not precise enough, I apologize. I just realized that I need the navbar to have a fixed width on desktop. I'm trying to adapt your answer, but I will edit my question. Sorry about that? I hope it's more clear now what I need.

Comment: Zafar I've fixed the problem in [another way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094787/fixed-width-div-on-right-fill-remaining-width-div-on-left) but this is the correct answer to the question I mad, so I will accept it, thanks a lot.

Comment: np. and yeah, that is a nice solution.